# How to use 3-block VGG to classify three classes?

Tags: python-3.x, keras

I was using 3-VGG block to classify images as two classes for example dog and cat and I was able to do it. But when I tried to use the same for classifying 3 classes for example- dog, cat and pandas, I am getting valuerror. I am suspecting I need to update Dense layer code but couldn't able to find exact issue. Please help me to know what I am missing here.

I am using Python 3.7 and Keras for this classification.

```py
def define_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', padding='same',
                     input_shape=(200, 200, 3)))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', padding='same'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
    model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', padding='same'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    # compile model
    opt = SGD(lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)
    model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model


# run the test harness for evaluating a model
def run_test_harness():
    # define model
    model = define_model()
    # create data generator
    datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0 / 255.0)
    # prepare iterators
    train_it = datagen.flow_from_directory('D:/Proect/images/',
                                           class_mode='categorical', batch_size=64, target_size=(200, 200))
    label_map = train_it.class_indices
    print("label_map: ", label_map)
    # fit model
    model.fit_generator(train_it, steps_per_epoch=len(train_it), epochs=20, verbose=0)
    # save model
    model.save('my_model.h5')
```

I am getting following error-

> "at line 41, in run_test_harness
>       model.fit_generator(train_it, steps_per_epoch=len(train_it), epochs=20, verbose=0) ValueError: Error when checking target: expected
>   dense_2 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (3,)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

This is configured to do binary classification, for 3 classes you need:

```
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
```